# mongoose schema validation failed with findOneAndReplace

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a problem when i update data using mongoose "findOneAndReplace",
i recive a validation schema error,
specifically seems that the fields are empty.

with the same data i have no problem with other crud operation like "create" and "delete",
so is definitely not related with schema or data

anyway here my code:

**service in Angular**

```
    updateCustomer(customer){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.put(this.UpdateCustomer+'/'+customer._id, JSON.stringify(customer), {headers: headers})
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
}
```

**mongoose put**

```
app.put('/api/aggiorna_cliente/:id', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)) --> IS POPULATED
Clienti.findOneAndReplace(
    {_id:req.params.id},
    {$set:{
        address:req.body.address,
        brand:req.body.brand,
        cap:req.body.cap,
        city:req.body.city,
        civico:req.body.civico,
        email:req.body.email,
        fiscalcode:req.body.fiscalcode,
        provincia:req.body.provincia,
        utente:req.body.utente
        }
    }, 
    function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

**CLIENTI SCHEMA**

```
            const mongoose = require('mongoose');

        const clientiSchema = mongoose.Schema({
            utente:{
                type: String,
                required:true
            },
            cap:{
                type: Number,
                required:true
            },
            civico:{
                type: String,
                required:true
            },
            city:{
                type: String,
                required:true
            },  
            address:{
                type: String,
                required:true
            },
            fiscalcode:{
                type:String,
                required:true
            },
            email:{
                type:String,
                required:true
            },      
            brand:{
                type:String,
                required:true
            },      
            provincia:{
                province: String,
                sigle: String
            }
        });

        const Clienti = mongoose.model('Clienti',clientiSchema);
        module.exports = Clienti;
```

what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$set` with Mongoose (this is a native Mongo operator). The second argument must be an object containing the fields to update ([doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndReplace)). Don't add `$set`. Mongoose thinks that `$set` is the key to update, so it fails your validation.

```
Clienti.findOneAndReplace(
    {_id:req.params.id},
    {
        address:req.body.address,
        brand:req.body.brand,
        cap:req.body.cap,
        city:req.body.city,
        civico:req.body.civico,
        email:req.body.email,
        fiscalcode:req.body.fiscalcode,
        provincia:req.body.provincia,
        utente:req.body.utente
    },
```

Comment: good suggestion, thanks, but unfortunately don't seems to work

Comment: Well, it's what the documentation says... Define "It doesn't work"?

Comment: well, it seems to be a validation problem, here the message from console:

ValidationError: Clienti validation failed: brand: Path `brand` is required., email: Path `email` is required., fiscalcode: Path `fiscalcode` is required., address: Path `address` is required., city: Path `city` is required., civico: Path `civico` is required., 
cap: Path `cap` is required., utente: Path `utente` is required.


but in truth these fields are not empty

Comment: what if you `console.log()` your update object? Is it being logged correctly? With every key and every value?

Comment: well, yes i have put a console.log before findOneAndReplace

here what i get:
{"provincia":{"province":"Aosta","sigle":"AO"},"_id":"5ede0d15eee9e6380cfd4cbf","brand":"test","email":"test@test","fiscalcode":"01555510260","address":"via guaiane 95","city":"noventa di piave","civico":"32","cap":30020,"utente":"5ede0ab57dd94706f0b0f30b","__v":0}

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue and got it resolved by passing null as third parameter, so for your question, it will be

```js
Clienti.findOneAndReplace(
    {_id:req.params.id},
    {
        address:req.body.address,
        brand:req.body.brand,
        cap:req.body.cap,
        city:req.body.city,
        civico:req.body.civico,
        email:req.body.email,
        fiscalcode:req.body.fiscalcode,
        provincia:req.body.provincia,
        utente:req.body.utente
    }, 
    null,
    function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
    });
});
```